# Problem with archive

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

On the terminal server windows 2003 is 7zip. The problem is that it does not follow the rules of the GPO. And users can use the archive as a explorer. while in Group Policy to use the explorer is prohibited. 
Can someone suggest how to withdraw from the situation, leaving users to archive?

Sorry, my English not good.. Ask questions

Comment: I believe what you are trying to say is that you have locked your system down and blocked all file browsing with Windows Explorer.  But the 7zip application doesn't use the standard windows file browser and can be used to bypass policies you are attempting to enforce with your group policies.

Answer (score 1):

What do the users need to archive?  Do you have to use 7zip?  Windows has a native zip functionality. If you need to handle other archive formats, you could try other archivers and their command line versions.

I think more information is needed to give a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

> By: Igor Pavlov (ipavlovProject — 7zip developer)
>   2009-04-20 08:14 No way now.

Found that at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=3228692&forum_id=45797). No GPO support.

Comment: Rian's right! I am trying to say this!

David Yu - Users use the format *.rar and Windows native zip functionality is not supported this format. :( I tried to use WinRAR  but it has the same problem and it shareware.

Igor Pavlov - Thank you for your reply, it is not very good. :( 

Can what a way to solve the problem? Teach users use Windows native zip this is an extreme solution. :)